# Como hago para usar una funcion y que funcione en paralelo al programa principal (que seguira funcionando) por medio de threading o hilos

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, hilos, clase

disculpen me estoy liando con esto, si creo esta funcion llamada greetings.py

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime

def time_messege():

    alarmtime = "18:46"

    #Aca es donde temo que se trabe porque necesito que esto ande para mandar un mensaje a una determinada hora pero que de mientras el programa general (el bot) siga respondiendo mensajes comunes, sin trabarse en este bucle
      
    while True: 
      
        lcltime = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

        if lcltime == alarmtime:

            #aca pondria el code de detectar canal y enviar
            print("is time!")

            break

        else:
            print("not yet")
            time.sleep(10)
```

y la llamo en otra funcion que es main.py con:

```py
#Para poner mensajes por tiempo
from core.modules.greetings import time_messege
```

como hago para llamar a la funcion greetings.py dentro de esta funcion que esta dentro del script main, "pero como threading o hilo para que el programa principal siga andando pero eso quede en paralelo y tire el mensaje en la hora establecida":

```
async def on_ready(self) -> None:
    print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user))
```

pero no entiendo a que te refieres a implementearle el procesamiento en paralelo?

Comment: Invesyiga hacerla del modulo subprocess y no veo que hayas implementado algún hilo

Comment: no, estaba viendo tutos pero no se como hacerlo, por eso pedia ayuda. Porque estoy muy  perdida con eso. Ya casi tengo el bot de atencion a clientes para discord casi completo, pero no le capto a lo de los hilos no se como implementarlo

Comment: puedes leer esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55946/multiprocesamiento-con-hilos-en-python)